# Bode plot multi phase margin

Tags: stability

When bode plot have multi phase margin how to decide the stability the transient would effected by which phase margin
[image]

Comment: Use the PM that is worst as a first approximation. As a more complete evaluation use a simulator.

Comment: The PM tells you how large the additional (unwanted) phase shift is to bring the closed loop to the stability limit. When you have 3 frequencies with zero loop gain there are 3 different frequencies which must be analyzed concerning the PM at this frequency. At each of these 3 frequencies there will be a specific - additional - phase shift within the loop which  would cause instability.

Comment: My understanding of this, and this may need clarifying by someone else, is that with an unconventional looking bode plot like that one where the magnitude plot crosses the unity loop gain line multiple times, the full Nyquist treatment is necessary with a Nyquist plot and application of the Nyquist criteria to determine if the system is stable. This situation highlights the limits on the usefulness of the Bode plot technique.

Comment: As the the above comment mentions, use the Nyquist plot.

Comment: @LvW can you give me a example?

Comment: @James I also use the nyquist plot bot it just tell me the stability but I don't know why
and I want to know which phase margin would affect my circuit transient

Comment: @James...The BODE plot contains exactly the same information as the Nyquist plot. Hence, the full stability criterion can also be applied using the BODE plot - however, in a modified form: We must analyze the number and the directions (!) of the 180deg (resp. 360deg) crossings of the phase response.

Comment: @Jason...your last question cannot be answered because in your example there is no "continuous" falling phase response and your transfer function contains - at least - one zero. In such a case  there is no direct relation between the phase margin(s) in the frequency domain and the transient response in the time domain.

Comment: @LvW ...and presumably determine the number of unstable open loop poles (number of open loop poles on RHS of s plane).

Comment: I am curious about how the multiple crossover frequency would affect the transient

Comment: @LvW what At each of these 3 frequencies there will be a specific - additional - phase shift within the loop which would cause instability mean